# the different combinations of a vector's values

Tags: c++, vector, combinations

Suppose I have a vector of n values, I want to get the different combinations of its values, for example: if I have vect = [a, b, c] the different combinations that I want are: [a, b, c], [a,b], [a,c], [b,c], [a], [b], [c]

Note that for example [a,b] is the same as [b,a] so I don't need to keep both of them.

Comment: You are looking for the 'power set' of your vector of values; to be absolutely accurate you are looking for the power set without the element [].  This (the empty set) corresponds to the number 0 in @Henrik's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count from `0` to `2^vector.size() - 1`. If bit i of your loop variable is 1, include `vector[i]` in your combination.

```
vector<char> v;
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('b');
v.push_back('c');
for (int counter = 0; counter < (1 << v.size()); ++counter)
{
    vector<char> combination;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (counter & (1 << i))
            combination.push_back(v[i]);
    }

    // do something with combination
}
```

Edit: if you want to exclude the empty set, start counting at 1.

Comment: @user995434 - Set a = 1, b = 2, c = 4. This will give you a one-to-one correspondence between the numbers 0..7 and the combinations of a, b, and c. Now my code runs through the numbers 0..7 and builds the corresponding combinations by examining the bits 0..2 (of value 1, 2, 4).

Answer (score 0):

Give you a pseudo code, please convert it to real code.

```
vector resultVec;
while (!inputVec.empty)
{
    char c = inputVec.pop_back();

    foreach(one in resultVec)
    {
         combined = combine c and one;
         resultVec.push_back(combined);
    }

    resultVec.push_back(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a function which can already do this for you. Let's call it `combinations`.

If you were going to implement your own version of this, `my_combinations`, you could do it by looking at the first element in your vector, calling `combinations` on the rest of the vector, and then combining your element with each of the combinations.

Once you'd implemented this, you could delegate to your own version of `combinations` instead of using the pre-existing one.